# Xades4j signature verification

Tags: xades4j

XAdES4j documentation says that

```
XAdES4j can verify signatures in any of the four main XAdES forms.
```

Does that mean that it verifies XAdES BES, EPES, T and C (and does not verify X, XL and A)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's correct. The support for extended forms is not completed. There's some work on the issue tracker by a contributing developer that adds support for extended forms, but it hasn't been possible to go through that work yet.